# Как удалить элемент из массива стейт в React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть функция добавление элемента в массив:

```js
function addOrders(item) {
    let isArray = true;

    songOrders.forEach(el => {
      if(el.id === item.id) {
        return isArray = false;
      }
    })

    if(isArray) {
      setSongOrders([...songOrders, item]);
    }
```

По аналогии надо написать функцию по удалению элемента из массива.

Пробовал с помощью функции filter:

```js
if(isArray) setSongOrders([...songOrders.filter(el => el !== item)]);
```

Но тогда при нажатие можно удалить только первый элемент, остальные же нельзя

Comment: Сделайте `findIndex` и по нему удалите.

Comment: Я бы вам советовал для начала изучить javaScript, а потом уже переходить к реакту. Почитайте про методы массивов. В вашем вопросе есть отрывки кода, дополните его, что бы было понятно, какая функция и где вызывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом начале описан тип. Не особо важно, просто для наглядности.

Две функции для добавления и удаления.

Также рекомендую почитать про [**Array.filter**](https://doka.guide/js/array-filter/) и [**Array.findIndex**](https://doka.guide/js/array-find-index/)

```js
type OrderType = {
  id: string
} 

const [orders, setOrders] = useState<OrderType[]>([])

const addOrder = (order:OrderType) => {
  setOrders((ords) => {
    const clone = [...ords]
    const existIdx = clone.findIndex(({id}) => id === order.id)
    if(existIdx !== -1){
      clone[existIdx] = order
      return clone
    }
    
    return [...clone, order]
  })  
}

const removeOrder = (order:OrderType) => {
  setOrders((ords) => {
    return  ords.filter(({id}) => id !== order.id)
  })
}
```